# PHP JASPER XML, not show data with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, jasper-reports, fpdf

i am using IReport, phpjasperxml , php and postgresql to show data in a report.
When I use Mysql so

```
$PHPJasperXML->connect("localhost","root","","sakila");
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray("localhost","root","","sakila");
```

The result is:

[image]

But When I use PostgreSQL so:

```
$PHPJasperXML->connect("localhost","postgres","admin1sql","SBF", "psql");
$PHPJasperXML->transferDBtoArray("localhost","postgres","admin1sql","SBF", 
"psql");
```

I get nothing:

[image]

Can someone help me with this problem? Thanks and Greets

Answer (score 0):

Solved, my apache only enabled for PDO POSTGRES, and php jasper xml dont use PDO

Uncomment in php.ini

extension=php_pgsql.dll

lol